# Syntax issues with MySQL procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have this procedure created from I could find on stack overflow. I want to get rows from all tables that have a certain column in them, for a specific value.
So:

- get all tables with the column
- get all rows from the tables that have column value of x

  ```
  @DELIMITER $$
  CREATE PROCEDURE db.selectStuff ()
  BEGIN
    DECLARE a varchar(100);
    DECLARE i CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME="my_column_name";
    OPEN i;
    read_loop: LOOP
      FETCH i INTO crt_table;
      SELECT * FROM crt_table WHERE my_column_name=some_id;
    END LOOP read_loop;
    CLOSE i;
  END$$
  @DELIMITER;
  call selectStuff();
  ```

I am getting this

*`[Code: 1064, SQL State: 42000]  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE i CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS ' at line 1`* when running this from **DBVisualizer Pro 9.5.7**

The select works.

UPDATE:
FROM the comments bellow I changed the code to:

```
@DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE selectStuff ()
BEGIN
  DECLARE s VARCHAR(300);
  DECLARE i CURSOR FOR SELECT CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ',c.TABLE_NAME,' where `my_column_name`=1') as s from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c WHERE c.COLUMN_NAME="my_column_name";
  OPEN i;
  do_stuff: LOOP
    FETCH i INTO s;
    PREPARE run FROM s;
    EXECUTE run;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE run;
  END LOOP do_stuff;
  CLOSE i;
END$$
@DELIMITER;

call selectStuff();
```

I am getting the same error.

**NOTE**: Running

```
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ',c.TABLE_NAME,' where `my_column_name`=1') as s from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c WHERE c.COLUMN_NAME="my_column_name"
```

Does actually provide the correct SQL statements that would get me what I want.

UPDATE: 
Running it in dbForge Studio Express:

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE PROCEDURE selectStuff()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done TINYINT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE s VARCHAR (3000);
  DECLARE i CURSOR FOR SELECT CONCAT("SELECT * FROM ", c.TABLE_NAME, " where my_column_name=1") as QUERY from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c WHERE c.COLUMN_NAME="my_column_name";
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
  OPEN i;
  do_stuff: LOOP
    FETCH i INTO s;
    IF done = 1 THEN LEAVE do_stuff;
    END IF;
    PREPARE stmt FROM s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  END LOOP do_stuff;
  CLOSE i;
END$
DELIMITER;

#call selectStuff();
```

I get some other error, but the cursor part passes.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  END LOOP do_stuff;
```

Comment: Change: `@DELIMITER $$` by `DELIMITER $$` and `@DELIMITER;` by `DELIMITER ;`. Avoid named variables (`crt_table`) like your tables and declare that variable.

Comment: If that is your error message, you delimiter doesn't work. Also: you need to use dynamic sql. `SELECT * FROM crt_table` will try to find the table `crt_table`, not the table with the value of that variable. See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30553954/how-to-select-all-tables-with-column-name-and-update-that-column) that does essentially the same you want to do, just doing an `update`. Or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38915800/search-for-a-string-in-any-column-of-all-tables) one for every column in all tables (although a bit too complicated).

Comment: @solarflare Can you take a look at the update. I am getting the correct query if I run the single line, but the declare still has that error. I am using DBVisualizer. I think the @ DELIMITER is needed.

Comment: Appearently for dbvisualizer, you have to use `@DELIMITER $$;` including the `;` (and `@DELIMITER ;$$` to end it). For your new error in the edit: you need to use `@variable` for your prepared statement, so use e.g. `set @dsql = s; PREPARE stmt FROM @dsql;`. At first sight, you should also include a schema in your query (either in the one from information_schema, or, in your dynamic sql, adduse the schema the table is in). And your last `DELIMITER;` has to include a space (`DELIMITER ;`)

Comment: Thanks, @Solarflare, I have posted an answer based on your help and another question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so answering my own question.

**Thank you @Solarflare for the very useful links.**

By following this answer [here](http://DELIMITER%20$%20DROP%20PROCEDURE%20IF%20EXISTS%20subset_partner_by_partner_id;%20CREATE%20PROCEDURE%20subset_partner_by_partner_id(IN%20id%20INT)%20BEGIN%20%20%20DECLARE%20s%20VARCHAR(255);%20%20%20DECLARE%20cont%20TINYINT%20DEFAULT%201;%20%20%20DECLARE%20crs%20CURSOR%20FOR%20SELECT%20CONCAT(%22SELECT%20*%20FROM%20%60%22,%20c.TABLE_NAME,%20%22%60%20where%20%60partner_id%60=%22,id)%20as%20Q%20from%20INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS%20c%20WHERE%20c.COLUMN_NAME=%22partner_id%22;%20%20%20DECLARE%20CONTINUE%20HANDLER%20FOR%20NOT%20FOUND%20SET%20cont=0;%20%20%20SET%20@sys_var%20=%20'';%20%20%20OPEN%20crs;%20%20%20WHILE%20cont=1%20DO%20%20%20%20%20FETCH%20crs%20INTO%20s;%20%20%20%20%20SET%20@sys_var%20=s;%20%20%20%20%20%20#SELECT%20@sys_var%20as%20'';%20%20%20%20%20PREPARE%20stmt%20FROM%20@sys_var;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20EXECUTE%20stmt;%20%20%20%20%20DEALLOCATE%20PREPARE%20stmt;%20%20%20END%20WHILE;%20%20%20CLOSE%20crs;%20END$%20DELIMITER;), I was able to get to the last Update in the question above. 
Seems that the errors were caused by the fact that the `PREPARE` statement cannot refer to a local variable, as explained in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985362/syntax-error-on-using-declare-and-prepared-statement-inside-create-procedure)

> A statement prepared in stored program context cannot refer to stored procedure or function parameters or local variables because they go out of scope when the program ends and would be unavailable were the statement to be executed later outside the program. As a workaround, refer instead to user-defined variables, which also have session scope;

**THUS**, the final code is this:

```
DELIMITER $
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS myName;
CREATE PROCEDURE myName(IN id INT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE s VARCHAR(255);
  DECLARE cont TINYINT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE crs CURSOR FOR SELECT CONCAT("SELECT * FROM `", c.TABLE_NAME, "` where `my_column`=",id) as Q from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c WHERE c.COLUMN_NAME="my_column";
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET cont=0;
  SET @sys_var = ''; 
  #THIS is where we declare a user defined variable to 
  #which we pass the actual string we want to execute as sql
  OPEN crs;
  WHILE cont=1 DO
    FETCH crs INTO s;
    SET @sys_var =s; 
    #SELECT @sys_var as ''; #this is just to test if the strings are correct
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sys_var;   
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  END WHILE;
  CLOSE crs;
END$
DELIMITER;
```

Notice how I am still fetching the cursor into the `varchar`, but then I am also setting the variable `sys_var` to have the same value, before passing it to `PREPARE`
I have also switched to a `WHILE DO` because it's **easier for me** to use, **no** other reason.

*Note: I have also added a parameter, but it isn't relevant for the question.*